# Create image with file contents

Tags: javascript, image, filereader

I have a drag&drop box where users will drop an image into. I wanted to create a preview before uploading. I have the contents of the image, which contains hundreds of lines of something like this:

[image: png contents]

Is there a way to display the image with its contents?
My current code for reading and assigning:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(uploadedfile[0]);
reader.onload = function (e) {
      filecontents = this.result;
      reader.abort();
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = filecontents;
      $('#drop p').html('<img src="'+image.src+'"/>');
}
```

Comment: Did you post a screenshot of what your image looks like in a text editor? Are you trying to compose a [`data:` URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple & efficient to do this, no `FileReader` required, assuming `uploadedfile` is an "array" of `File`s or `Blob`s:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = URL.createObjectURL(uploadedfile[0]);
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems I was over thinking it.